# Python implantation of a while loop that checks if a file contains new data

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I am trying to write a while true loop that checks the last line of a text file - `TransactionFile.txt` periodically (every 10 seconds) which contains data of the transactions being appended to the file.

Basically I have two programs one that appends the users transaction into a file and the other the reads the transaction, both of which are running concurrently.

What I'm having trouble with is is determining if the current transaction in `TransactionFile.txt` has changed or not.

This is my function for doing so

```
def transactionCheck():
    threading.Timer(10.0, transactionCheck).start()
    fileSecLast = None
    while True:
        try:
            file = open('TransactionFile.txt', 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('TransactionFile.txt could not found.')
            break
        else:
            file = open('TransactionFile.txt', 'r')
            global fileLast
            fileLast = file.readlines()[-1]
            file.close
            if fileLast == fileLast:
                print('New transaction data found.')
                print(fileLast)
                callfunctionNonce = calcNonce()
            elif fileLast == fileSecLast:
                print('No new transaction data found.')
                break          
            break
        break
```

Which gives output of this:

```
TransactionFile.txt could not found.
TransactionFile.txt could not found.
TransactionFile.txt could not found.
New transaction data found.
MOWZ575728::max::sam::67890::2018-05-19 13:11:50.250116

New transaction data found.
MOWZ575728::max::sam::67890::2018-05-19 13:11:50.250116

New transaction data found.
MOWZ575728::max::sam::67890::2018-05-19 13:11:50.250116

New transaction data found.
DOYU363556::geoff::tim::14515::2018-05-19 09:12:06.250116
```

What I would like to achieve is that if no new transactions have been written to `TransactionFile.txt` output `No new transaction data found.` instead of printing out the same transaction again. How should I go about doing this?

My intended output should be something like this:

```
TransactionFile.txt could not found.
TransactionFile.txt could not found.

New transaction data found.
MOWZ575728::max::sam::67890::2018-05-19 09:11:50.250116

No new transaction data found.
No new transaction data found.

New transaction data found.
DOYU363556::geoff::tim::14515::2018-05-19 09:12:06.250116
```

Thank you for the feedback and help.

If my question is unclear I'll try my best to explain it differently.

Comment: Maybe add a “New transaction” flag to the beginning or end of each transaction and then only return transactions with said flag after removing the flag from the transaction data.

Comment: You are comparing a variable with itself `if fileLast == fileLast`, which is always true, so even with no new transaction, you are getting the false output. You should use a new variable, say - `recentFileLast` for current iteration and compare with previous `fileLast` to decide if any changes are there.

Comment: Does the other program only append or does it completly overwrite the file? Also it would be nice to have a minimum other program, so we can test.

Comment: Why is there a `while True` loop? You are breaking out of it instantly.

Comment: @MegaIng the other program appends new transactions to the file.

Comment: Then my solution should work

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it way to complicated. If you can manage to make sure the file exits from the beginning, this should do it:

```
def transactionCheck():
    file = open("TransactionFile.txt", 'r')
    while True:
        line = file.readline().strip()
        if line:
            print("New transaction:")
            print(line)
            print()
        else:
            print("No new transaction")
        time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never give a value to `fileSecLast`and the if condition in not true. Try this:

```
def transactionCheck():
threading.Timer(10.0, transactionCheck).start()
fileSecLast = None
while True:
    try:
        file = open('TransactionFile.txt', 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('TransactionFile.txt could not found.')
        break
    else:
        file = open('TransactionFile.txt', 'r')
        global fileLast
        fileLast = file.readlines()[-1]
        file.close
        if fileLast == fileSecLast:
            print('No new transaction data found.')
            break 
        else:
            print('New transaction data found.')
            print(fileLast)
            callfunctionNonce = calcNonce()
            fileSecLast = fileLast
        break
    break
```